# Xcode hide self created button

Tags: iphone, uibutton, core-animation

I created a button programmatically:

```
UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
myButton.frame = CGRectMake(290, 120, 40,20); // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
[myButton setTitle:@"Back" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// add targets and actions
[myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(backLogin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 
// add to a view
[myButton setAlpha:0];
[self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Now I would like to hide this button again using another method and use animation to make the button fade away (!). 
Obviously, I cannot use the variable myButton again and I don't want to make the variable global. Removing the Subview from the layer won't animate I guess. Do you have an idea? I can't make it to work... Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for `myButton.hidden = YES`

Comment: Xcode is the IDE, this question is not related at all with it. Rather add the "iPhone" label

Comment: Why you don't want it to define in your class file normally?

Comment: On the internet, they post the code to create a button with a local variable like this everywhere. To just declare the variable , but as a beginner I didn't think of using a regular instance variable when not using IB (but it's indd the same) :-s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going about this the right way, but first of all, you're adding an invisible button to your view.  Assuming you meant to add the button with an alpha of 1, here we go.

Fist of all, set a tag for the button:

```
myButton.tag = 1;
```

Any will do, as long as you're not using that tag for something else.

Next in your other method we can iterate through the subviews in your view controller and we can find the view with the tag of 1, and set it's alpha to 0 with a nice fade effect:

```
for (UIButton *button in self.view.subviews) {
    if (button.tag == 1) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0 animations:^ {
            button.alpha = 0;
        }];
    }
}
```

However, this is really a bad way to go about it, and I would highly suggest just creating an instance variable.

Comment: Hey you are right, very stupid of me: I'm not experienced so I didn't think of it. I found this code on the internet, but indeed I solved it now by creating a UIButton instance in the header file, set @property - synthesize - release and now I can use it. I will accept your answer, since your last phrase made me come to the solution! (Thanks for the rest as well :-)) The thing is, I wanted to initialize the button with alpha 0, since this way I can make it appear with animation.

Comment: Ah, I gotcha.  Glad to be of some help. ;)